# Should I use "even though" or "although" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence

> Even though we were becoming closer and closer, we remained just as
>   friends.
>
> Although we were becoming closer and closer, we remained just as friends.

Which is the one above correct?

Comment: *Though* might be even better.

Comment: On a different note, *as* seems dispensable.

Comment: Sentence two is better.  I would also eliminate the word "as":  Although we were becoming closer and closer, we remained just friends.  Might you be talking about a relationship between a male and a female?  If so, you might be describing a "platonic" relationship, one in which there is no romantic involvement or commitment.  For a humorous perspective on the "platonic" relationship, see the scene in the movie "When Harry Met Sally," in which Harry insists that a man and a woman cannot be just friends!  Funny!

Comment: @rhetorician Yeah, I saw the movie. I think it's truth. Until, today I haven't been able to build a friendship with a woman (and I've been trying really hard).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Although" is a way to show a contrast between what you say and what it is.

"Even though" is preferred when you say something that brings to a negative concept, but the result is positive. "example: Even though Einstein took an F in math, he won the Nobel price"

So, in this case, I think that is better with "although".

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard that. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: isn't there contrast between F grade and his Nobel Prize of Einstein? why can't we say 'Although Einstein took an F in math, he won the Nobel Prize'?

Comment: btw, the correct spelling is Prize not Price